# Difference between codes of quick sort

Tags: algorithm

I want to know how this two codes give same result. But the logic is different.

Both do sorting. But there is different types of partition in both the code. How is that defined.

Can anybody please explain me this.

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/

```
/* C++ implementation of QuickSort */
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

// A utility function to swap two elements 
void swap(int* a, int* b) 
{ 
    int t = *a; 
    *a = *b; 
    *b = t; 
} 

/* This function takes last element as pivot, places 
the pivot element at its correct position in sorted 
array, and places all smaller (smaller than pivot) 
to left of pivot and all greater elements to right 
of pivot */
int partition (int arr[], int low, int high) 
{ 
    int pivot = arr[high]; // pivot 
    int i = (low - 1); // Index of smaller element 

    for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++) 
    { 
        // If current element is smaller than the pivot 
        if (arr[j] < pivot) 
        { 
            i++; // increment index of smaller element 
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]); 
        } 
    } 
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]); 
    return (i + 1); 
} 

/* The main function that implements QuickSort 
arr[] --> Array to be sorted, 
low --> Starting index, 
high --> Ending index */
void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high) 
{ 
    if (low < high) 
    { 
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now 
        at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high); 

        // Separately sort elements before 
        // partition and after partition 
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1); 
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high); 
    } 
} 

/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(int arr[], int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        cout << arr[i] << " "; 
    cout << endl; 
} 

// Driver Code 
int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = {10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5}; 
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
    quickSort(arr, 0, n - 1); 
    cout << "Sorted array: \n"; 
    printArray(arr, n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The second code is taken from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7h1s2SojIRw
Second code is

```
    #include <stdio.h>

 #include<stdlib.h>

 void swap(int * x, int * y) {
   int temp = * x;
   * x = * y;
   * y = temp;
 }
 int partition(int A[], int l, int h) {
   int pivot = A[l];
   int i = l, j = h;
   do {
     do {
       i++;
     } while (A[i] <= pivot);
     do {
       j--;
     } while (A[j] > pivot);
     if (i < j) swap( & A[i], & A[j]);
   } while (i < j);
   swap( & A[l], & A[j]);
   return j;
 }
 void QuickSort(int A[], int l, int h) {
   int j;
   if (l < h) {
     j = partition(A, l, h);
     QuickSort(A, l, j);
     QuickSort(A, j + 1, h);
   }

 }
 int main() {
   int A[] = {
     11,
     13,
     7,
     12,
     16,
     9,
     24,
     5,
     10,
     3
   }, n = 10, i;
   QuickSort(A, n);
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d ", A[i]);
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Can you make your second code more readable?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't get the question, you have two sorting algo, it is obvious that the result will be the same (sorted array), can you redefine your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But what has made you so curious?
The first code uses Lomuto partition, the second one (as I can see in your long line) uses Hoare's partition. You can read about details of these partitions at Wiki [Quicksort page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) or in numerous algorithm books.

But both partition algorithms provide the main result - lesser elements move on the left side, greater elements move on the right side, and partition function returns index of separator element.

The main Quicksort routine can use any partition subroutine that gives needed kind of element separation. Note that intermediate state might differ, but final result should be similar.